# cURL library is not working correctly after the first ~2 hours of running

Tags: c++, curl, https

Ok, so my problem is basically this. I coded up a program that downloads a JSON from an HTTPS URL every ~5 seconds using cURL. I left it running overnight and after running perfectly for about 2 hours, every single connection to the URL failed. I had internet running, at least when I woke up and checked, but the program kept on failing. As soon as I restarted the program it started working again. I tried reproducing the problem by pulling my ethernet code for a minute and then connecting it back but the program worked perfectly after the connection had been re-established. Help? :D

Context:
Developing, compiling and running in Xcode 4.6.2, linked to cURL 7.24.0.

I have a `JSONDownloader` class defined by me, I call `down.get("https://url.of.the/info");` to fetch the information.

This is the code for JSONDownloader:

```
std::string JSONDownloader::DownloadedResponse;
bool JSONDownloader::valid_;

int JSONDownloader::dataStore(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *buffer_in) {
    if (buffer_in != NULL)
    {         
        DownloadedResponse.erase();
        DownloadedResponse.append(data, size * nmemb);

        return (int)(size * nmemb);
    } else throw "error in HTTPS get!";

    return 0;
}

std::string JSONDownloader::get(std::string URL) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important
    std::ostringstream oss;
    curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    curl_slist_append( headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_slist_append( headers, "charsets: utf-8");
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,dataStore);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,20);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (CURLE_OK == res)
        {
            valid_ = true;
            return DownloadedResponse;
        } else valid_ = false;
    }

    return "error in HTTP get!";
}

bool JSONDownloader::valid() {
    return valid_;
}
```

After the 2 hours, the function returned only `"error in HTTP get!"` for every call, and the `valid_` flag was always set to false. Right now, I rewrote it to return `res`, see if it gives me the reason for my errors, I'll update you guys with the info. Any insights? Thank you!

**UPDATE:** It fails with error 56, CURLE_RECV_ERROR, described by the documentation as "Failure with receiving network data."

Comment: Maybe the API is blocking you because it thinks you're DDoS-ing. Is this your api or someone else's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't cleaning up the connection after it has finished. You need to call [`curl_easy_cleanup()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html) in order to completely close the connection and release the resources it have been allocated for it.

From the LibCURL website:

> This function must be the first function to call, and it returns a CURL easy handle that you must use as input to other easy-functions. curl_easy_init initializes curl and this call MUST have a corresponding call to curl_easy_cleanup(3) when the operation is complete.

Below is the change needed to handle the cleanup

```
std::string JSONDownloader::get(std::string URL)
{
    CURL *curl;
    // .... snipped code
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        // .... snipped code
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);  // <---- clean up before we return!

        if (CURLE_OK == res)
        {
            valid_ = true;
            return DownloadedResponse;
        } else valid_ = false;

    }

    return "error in HTTP get!";
}
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed it! Thank you!